# id auto_inc column, but no primary key?

Tags: database, postgresql

I apologize for the bad title, but I wasn't sure how else to phrase it.

Let's imagine for a moment that I wanted to create a `us_states` table as follow:

```sql
create table us_states
(
    id   serial,
    name varchar(256) not null constraint us_states_pk primary key,
    code varchar(256) not null
);
```

What tangible benefits, if any, are there to having an auto incremental id column in a db_table if I don't plan on leveraging it as the primary key for said db_table?

Comment: Well each entry will get it's own lightweight Id value without the "complexities" a primary key would bring, such as unique constants, indexing, foreign key mechanisms,.etc. also you'd get to see how many entries there have been in the table since you created it.

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I totally understand your statement now. Thank you so much for the wonderful answer.

Comment: Auto increment will just ensure you don't have to manually insert the ID value on each insert. A primary key can still be auto incremental or not, but then you have to make a mechanism that ensures your newly inserted  row has a unique value. Something you save some computational time by just ensuring the new row gets the "probably max value+1" as it's primary key/id  as for the complexities... I suggest you read the manual... Or a lecture about primary keys and it's functions

Comment: Will do. Thank you so much!

Comment: Unrelated, but: the supposedly "magic" value 256 for the maximum length of a varchar does not imply any performance or storage optimizations over e.g. 260 or 275 in case you assumed, that 256 is somehow "better" than a higher value.

Comment: I didn't know people did it for performance or storage optimizations. The first job I had working with DBs, they had "varchar(256)" on almost everything so it became a habit. I always assumed it was a "best practice" thing, although I'll admit I've never cared enough to try and find out why it was potentially considered "best practice"

If the situation calls for it, I have no problem setting it to a higher value (i.e., 1024, 2056, etc).

Comment: How about shorter? Even if completely spelled *Washington District of Columbia* is only 31 characters, all other state names are < 16 characters. "varchar(40)" seems plenty large enough.

Comment: Very good point. I will go ahead and do that. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is zero value in adding an auto-incremented numerical column if it isn't a primary key or unique constraint.

If you have a unique column like `name` in your case, there are only two considerations not to use it as primary key:

- storing a number instead of the name in tables that reference this one will save space
- it is painful and should be avoided to modify primary key columns, so if the names change as part of the normal operation, it makes sense to use a different column as primary key